# Moving the data from Excel which have Dynamic column names to a table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am creating a SSIS package in which i have to move data from Excel to a table in SQL server. Excel file is like Source Assistant in data flow task.

Number columns in Excel file won't change but column names will change dynamically.

For example, In 2017 excel will look like this:

```
SId Name  Jan2017 Feb2017
1   name1  10      20
2   name2  30      40
```

in 2018, it will look like this:

```
SId Name  Jan2018 Feb2018
1   name1  50      60
2   name2  70      80
```

Once in every year I will run this Job to move the data from excel to DB. I have to movie this kind of data in to a table which have columns like below.

When i run this Job in 2017, data should be filled like below.

```
SId Name   Jan     Feb
1   name1  10      20
2   name2  30      40
```

When i run this Job in 2018, data should be filled like below.

```
SId Name   Jan    Feb
1   name1  50      60
2   name2  70      80
```

How can i handle this kind of data.

Comment: Do your columns positions also change or just the names and the positions remain the same?

Comment: Hi Jacob. Thanks for the reply. columns positions might change.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case can you at least be sure that each month will always contain the same value? Like `Jan2017` and `Jan2018` will never be missing `Jan`?

Comment: Yes It won't miss Jan. Month name will be there always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution overview

1. Exclude column names in first row in excel connection, use sql command as data access mode and Read data from the second row
2. Alias column names in the Excel Source -> Columns

   ```
   F1  F2     F3     F4
   SId Name   Jan    Feb
   ```

## Detailed Solution

You can follow my answer at [Importing excel files having variable headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437513/importing-excel-files-having-variable-headers/47491497#47491497) it is solving a very similar case.